# Android: how to disable top left back button from SubSettings

Tags: android, android-activity

From Android Jellybeans, all sub-activities of Settings activity are having this back button at top left corner which calls the Settings activity. It behaves more like a 'up' button for navigation purpose.

I have android code, and I want to disable this button for few sub-activities like display, sound etc. in my build.

Any suggestions, where do I have to modify to disable this? 
I tried out removing

```
android:parentActivityName
```

tag from particular Activity in the Manifest file, but it didn't work.

Comment: Post some code and if possible then post design.

Comment: I am ready to change the frameworks too, if required. Basically I don't want this 'up' button in the shape of '<' at top left corner of few activities like 'sound'/'display'/'storage'/'battery' etc. I thought this would be quite easy by just removing the tag "parentActivityName" in Manifest file, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

Comment: How do I get getActionBar() in sub-settings-activities. In android-root/packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/fuelgauge/PowerUsageSummary.java which extends PreferenceFragment. I think PreferenceFragment doesn't support getActionBar() method. There are other classes as well as PowerUsageSummary where preferenceFragment is used. How to proceed in such case?