# Android 8.0, startActivityForResult settings, not go back to my App if user click the top left Back button

Tags: android, settings, android-8.0-oreo

I open a setting activity using:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS), OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
```

In Android 8.0 There is a back button in the top left corner of the setting activity.

If user click that button, it would go the Settings App.
But it should be go back to the calling App, just like when clicking the system Back button.

[image]

The reason is that, in 8.0, the top left back button in sub-settings is bind to the Setting app.

I want to either disable that top left back button. Or make the button point to my App.

This question is more or less same as:

[Android: how to disable top left back button from SubSettings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24821828/android-how-to-disable-top-left-back-button-from-subsettings)

I ask because I don't understand how to apply that answer. And there may be some other workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can apply in intent calling

```
intent.putExtra("finishActivityOnSaveCompleted", true);
```

after that you can start intent
this may be helpful to solve your problem